# CouchDB Replication overwrites Documents

Tags: couchdb, replication

I know that when you create a Document on Database A, replicate the Database, then make changes to it on DB A and DB B and THEN replicate again, you’ll get a conflict but both Versions exist in the Revision Tree.

But when you create a Doc with an Id XY on DB A and then create a Doc with the same Id but different content on DB B and then replicate, only one of the Version exists. The other one gets overwritten.

Is the reason for that, that because both documents have no version they descend from and so the Replication Algorithm can’t know that they both exist?

And if yes is there a way of saving both Versions?

Use Case is that there are two databases, one local, one online. they biderectionally sync. On both DBs User create docs. But I need to make sure IF the connection fails for a while that both CAN still create docs and I can merge them whenever the connection is back. I guess the hard Part here is the CREATE instead of UPDATE right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, and for total clarity, CouchDB does *not* overwrite data. The only way for data you've written to be forgotten is to make a successful update to a document.

CouchDB will introduce new branches (aka conflicts) during replication to preserve all divergences of content. If what you've seen is reproducible then it's a bug. Below is my transcript though which shows that CouchDB indeed preserves both revisions as expected;

> curl 127.0.0.1:5984/db1 -XPUT
>   {"ok":true}
>
> curl 127.0.0.1:5984/db2 -XPUT
>   {"ok":true}
>
> curl 127.0.0.1:5984/db1/mydoc -XPUT -d '{"foo":true}'
>
> {"ok":true,"id":"mydoc","rev":"1-89248382088d08ccb7183515daf390b8"}
>
> curl 127.0.0.1:5984/db2/mydoc -XPUT -d '{"foo":false}'
>
> {"ok":true,"id":"mydoc","rev":"1-1153b140e4c8674e2e6425c94de860a0"}
>
> curl 127.0.0.1:5984/_replicate -Hcontent-type:application/json -d '{"source":"db1","target":"db2"}'
>
> {"ok":true,...}
>
> curl '127.0.0.1:5984/db2/mydoc?conflicts=true'
>
> {"_id":"mydoc","_rev":"1-89248382088d08ccb7183515daf390b8","foo":true,"_conflicts":["1-1153b140e4c8674e2e6425c94de860a0"]}

Comment: You Sir are Correct! And i feel very stupid. For some reason i Expected both Version to be visible in Futon for Example. But if get the Document with {conflics:"true"} or conflicts="true" both Version show up and I can take care of the Merging. THANK YOU

Comment: You're very welcome. We're replacing futon with fauxton and there's a plan to build a UI that shows conflicts (and helps you resolve them!).